# Winding the faces of a platonic solid?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algorithms, platonic-solids

Given the set of cartesian coordinates of the n vertexes of a platonic solid, is there a way to number the vertexes `{0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}` in some order, and then describe the m faces as ordered sequences of these numbered vertexes such that they form a right-handed winding of each face away from the origin?

Comment: Yes. Are you asking for a particular listing of vertices for a particular polyhedron (doable, but tedious)? An efficient algorithm you can program (I don't know of one offhand, but one may well exist)? Something else...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Yes, I'm looking for an algorithm - or at least some rough pattern of formula.  Something better than plotting them and doing it by hand.

Comment: I'm no expert, but the usual approach (taken by, e.g., [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)) is perhaps incrementally to endow the set of vertices with additional incidence data (oriented edges and faces). There are computational geometry experts on site, such as [Joseph O'Rourke](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/), who may be able to give you more detailed pointers.